# I cannot see the icon preview in menu options - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, icons

Does anybody know why I cannot see the preview image for icons? This happens in VS Code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `uses-material-design: true` in `pubspec.yaml` for the icons to be included in the app.

Then you need to stop the emulator and run it from fresh.